# What does a system load of 16 mean on a 4 core processor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can't seem to find anyone reporting a similar statistic and hence can't find an explanation. The 3570K is a 4 core 4 thread cpu, so the maximum load should 4.0 I assume? Yet I can repeatedly see a load of 16.0 when running certain applications (transcoding on Plex for example).

Comment: Check /proc/cpuinfo to see how many “CPU’s” your Linux kernel makes from your CPU spec. Then a load up to that number is simplified you don’t have cpu contention, loads beyond the number of cpu’s means you do.

Answer (score 2):

A load of 16 means that there are 16 processes ready to run, on average, over a period of 1min, 5min and 15min. That is independent of the number of cores you have.

This "ready to run" includes both processes that want the CPU and processes that are waiting for a disk operation to complete. Disk operations are not interruptible and the process counts as "ready to run".

So you either have a high CPU load or a high disk load, or both.